# Make posts non-sticky

Tags: sticky-post

I have around 200 posts. I want to make all posts non-sticky except 4 posts. I know the id of those 4 posts. How can I do it? Using plugin or sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple script which you run once and remove. The idea is to replace the sticky post array with an array of the 4 desired ID's

**PHP 5.4+ version - short array syntax**

```
add_action( 'init', function ()
{
    // Define our new array
    $stickies = [1,2,3,4]; // Change to match your own ID's

    // Update the sticky posts option
    update_option( 
        'sticky_posts', // Option name 
        $stickies // New value 
    );
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

**Pre PHP5.4 version**

```
add_action( 'init', function ()
{
    // Define our new array
    $stickies = array( 1,2,3,4 ); // Change to match your own ID's

    // Update the sticky posts option
    update_option( 
        'sticky_posts', // Option name 
        $stickies // New value 
    );
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Just one note on your edit, the array syntax I used is perfectly valid, **BUT** it does not work on PHP versions older than PHP 5.4. If you received an error regarding the array syntax, you are on a dinosaur version of PHP. At this stage, you should not be using any version below PHP 5.6 as the all previous versions are EOL'ed (*PHP 5.5 will EOL in July*), using this versions will lead to security issues ;-)

Comment: Thank you once again for this information. I will update it. :)